# How to change source of fabric.Object to make it point to hi-res image file

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I use fabricjs. I need to change the source of an image object in the canvas to point it to its hi-res image without changing its properties so that when I use `canvas.toDataURLWithMultiplier('jpeg', 2)` the image quality is not affected.

Please help me figure out a way to do this.